# Are there universal trade logs on Interactive Brokers?

Tags: options, online-tools, interactive-brokers

I would be interested in seeing all trades of a day, say, in a specific option product. Not my trades, but all trades made by any market participant.

Does Interactive Brokers (IB) offer this information and if yes, how do I retrieve it? Who (else) does offer this service?

Answer (score 1):

No broker would have any  idea what traders at other brokers are doing nor would any broker collate the trading by any specific account holder and make that information available to you.

OTOH, you can see all trades made in a specific option product by looking at Time & Sales but you would need some clever data scraping tool for active options since there could be 100s of pages of data, even 1,000s for a frequent flier like the SPY.

Comment: I guess I am looking for your OTOH.